# How to highlight double-clicked word in input after input.select()

Tags: javascript, input, selection

There is an input with some text. All text in this input has to be selected when input is focusing (first click on input) and specific word has to be selected when second click on input occurs.

I try to implement the same functionality that URL-bar in Chrome(Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)) has.

Current behavior of input you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/deaamod1s/rh5mw0e4/23/

The only solution I see it's to check was the input double-clicked or not and after that if input wasn't double-clicked - to do `input.select()`

```
input.onfocus = function(e) {
        let hasValueWhenGotFocused = false;

        if (input.value) {
            hasValueWhenGotFocused = true;
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (hasValueWhenGotFocused && this.className.indexOf("doubleclicked") == -1) {
                    this.select();
            } else {
                this.classList.remove("doubleclicked");
            }
        },400);
  }

    input.ondblclick = function(e){
        this.classList.add('doubleclicked');
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML as part of the code snippet, to better understand what the question is here.

Comment: @Mendel, https://jsfiddle.net/deaamod1s/rh5mw0e4/23/

Comment: ...and so what's the issue?

Comment: @gaetanoM, "double-clicked" word isn't getting selected after I do second click on word

Comment: @ВладЖадченко  Hi, I just tried and it works in CHROME, FF, EDGE and IE (last versions). Please, two consecutive clicks are not a double click. Can you create a fiddle in order to show the issue using my  fiddle? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) event handler is always executed before the [ondblclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondblclick). 
I suggest to delay the focus handler so that it can be executed after a possible double click (updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3y9phu/1/)):

```js
input.ondblclick = function (e) {
    // set....
    this.dataset.dblclick = true;
}

input.onfocus = function (e) {
    this.dataset.dblclick = false;
    setTimeout(function (_this) {
        // if not set...
        if (_this.dataset.dblclick == "false") {
            _this.select();
        } else {
            // remove ...
            delete _this.dataset.dblclick;
        }
    }, 200, this);
}
```

```html
Try to select second word using only two click<br>
<input type="text" id="input" value="sdsas select_me">
```